# Pycharm does not start because "No JDK found"

Tags: pycharm

I installed Pycharm, which automatically created then a shortcut at the Applications Menu. But the shortcut does not work and shows the message

```
No JDK found. Please validate either PYCHARM_JDK, JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME    environment variable points to valid JDK installation.
```

But Java is installed:

```
java version "1.8.0_73"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_73-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.73-b02, mixed mode).
```

Besides, if I run the script "pycharm.sh" from the command line, it works.

Comment: Try to add `JAVA_HOME` to  environment Variables `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk` change `java-7-openjdk` with you actual version

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27625777/cannot-start-pycharm) post. I believe your issue is similar.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue today myself. I installed pycharm via getdeb repository so my installation folder is located at: `/usr/share/pycharm/bin`. In order to fix this issue steps are:

1. `sudo gedit` or `sudo xed` `/usr/share/pycharm/bin/pycharm.sh`
2. find Line: JDK=`update-alternatives --list java | grep java-8 | sed 's,jre/bin/java,,' and replace it with JDK = '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/' or JDK = '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/' if you're using openjdk.
3. Save and exit, then try running pycharms again. You should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and I fixed it by doing:

```
# Open & modify pycharm's executable
sudo nano /usr/share/pycharm/bin/pycharm.sh
# Edit line: 95
JDK=`update-alternatives --get-selections | grep "java " | awk '{gsub("/bin/java", ""); print $3}'`
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to .bashrc/.profile. This worked for me.

```
export PYCHARM_JDK=$JAVA_HOME
export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--master local[2] pyspark-shell"
```

Assuming you have set JAVA_HOME. If not, use path to Java home directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind installing a snap, you can also try:

```
sudo snap install pycharm-community --classic
```

Start it (the first time) from a terminal with

```
pycharm-community
```

After closing, search for it in the dash and drag the icon to the launcher.